# Best way to repeat list of values for `IN` clauses

Tags: postgresql, where-in

I need to use the same list of values in several `IN` clauses and I tried doing that with a `WITH` statement, but can't get it to work correctly.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM parent WHERE
id IN (SELECT first_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
       SELECT second_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
       SELECT third_id FROM child WHERE id=119896) OR
id IN (SELECT was_first_id FROM parent WHERE id IN (SELECT first_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT second_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT third_id FROM child WHERE id=119896)) OR
id IN (SELECT was_second_id FROM parent WHERE id IN (SELECT first_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT second_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT third_id FROM child WHERE id=119896)) OR
id IN (SELECT was_third_id FROM parent WHERE id IN (SELECT first_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT second_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT third_id FROM child WHERE id=119896));
```

I was hoping to make it so that the 3 queries that are combined in the `UNION ALL` could be defined in a `WITH` and then re-used to simplify the query, and it would be nice if it improved performance as well.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
SELECT *
FROM parent
WHERE (
  SELECT id IN (first_id, second_id, third_id)
  FROM child
  WHERE id = 119896
) OR (
  SELECT id IN (was_first_id, was_second_id, was_third_id)
  FROM parent
  WHERE (
    SELECT id IN (first_id, second_id, third_id)
    FROM child
    WHERE id = 119896
  )
);
```

<sup>(I don't know about performance - as per comments, it's really bad)</sup>

An alternative, using the [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) you suggested, would be

```
WITH child_ids AS (
  SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[first_id, second_id, third_id]) AS id
  FROM child
  WHERE id = 119896
), all_ids AS (
  SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[was_first_id, was_second_id, was_third_id]) AS id
  FROM parent
  JOIN child_ids USING (id) -- same as: WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM child_ids)
  UNION
  TABLE child_ids
)
SELECT *
FROM parent
JOIN all_ids USING (id) -- same as: WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM all_ids)
```

Comment: I don't think that returns the same result as the above query. Or at least, when I ran it on my data, I got 0 rows back, when the original query returns 4 rows.

Comment: Oh, if I add explicit table names, then it appears to work, but the performance ends up being really bad because it does a sequential scan and a filter check on each row.

Comment: @DaveJohansen Ah I feared the optimiser might not be clever enough for that :-/ See update, that should perform better (and also not repeat the selection from the `child` table)

Comment: Yes, that works significantly better! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [second solution by @Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68581748/231489), this also works as well:

```
WITH in_child(id) AS (
  SELECT first_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
  SELECT second_id FROM child WHERE id=119896 UNION ALL
  SELECT third_id FROM child WHERE id=119896
),
in_parent(id) AS (
 (SELECT id FROM in_child) UNION ALL
 (SELECT was_first_id FROM parent WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM in_child)) UNION ALL
 (SELECT was_second_id FROM parent WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM in_child)) UNION ALL
 (SELECT was_third_id FROM parent WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM in_child))
)
SELECT * FROM parent WHERE
id IN (SELECT id FROM in_parent);
```